# Automatic verification of database contents

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, automated-tests, verification

**Background**

I have a software component that writes data to a postgres database (into several tables) and I want to write an automatic functional test for this component. I already have a host of unit tests in place that check the subcomponents, but I'd like a test that checks the whole system end-to-end.

For each test run, I use a clean database (actually a completely new, this-test-run-only database). The software component is stable in the sense that given the same input, it will always write the same user data to the database.

The database design is relational, such that most tables contain foreign keys. Obviously, I don't want to check the value of these keys, because I don't want to rely on the fact that these keys are generated in a predictive manner by postgres.

Assume that there are no issues regarding user rights on the database, connection issues etc. Also disregard development/production disparities.

I currently use a number of `select` statements to produce a textual "dump" of the database and compare it to a reference dump (ignoring whitespace and so on), but this seems rather clumsy. Also, this doesn't take into account the relationships between the tables. Extending the current approach to deal with this doesn't strike me as maintainable at all, should the database layout ever change.

My software as well as the testing framework is written in C++, the testing scripts are simple bash scripts. I'm open to use any language to achieve this.

**Question**

How can I automatically verify the database contents in "the database way"?

Even better would be an approach that doesn't rely on postgres as the backend.

Comment: I would stay with the text-diff. Instead of dumping the table contents manually, I would use the output of pg_dump and compare that to a dump from the reference DB.

Comment: It almost *sounds* like you're really just proposing to test the database engine. If your code writes N rows to the database without generating a trappable error, then what might cause something *besides* those N rows to be stored?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Well, the software itself is **far** more complex, but it is expected to yield the same output every time. The test is more to check that the data are collected and processed correctly than that the storage in the database itself works.

Comment: @wildplasser This leaves the problem of automatically assigned keys, does it not?

Comment: If you mean "SERIAL" keys (sequences) these are assigned deterministically. So: they can only be assigned in a different order if the testing client(s) code behaves differently. The other usual suspects are dates, times and timestamps, you'll need to handle these as spacial cases.

Answer (score 1):

[pgTap](http://pgtap.org/) is a testing framework for PostgreSQL. You can use it to test both the structure and [the content](http://pgtap.org/documentation.html#results_eq) of a PostgreSQL database. I've used it on projects that had to meet certain contractual standards for seeded data (data for "lookup" tables like state codes and abbreviations, delivery carriers, user roles, etc.). It has worked well for that purpose.

But I don't yet see a compelling reason to abandon your current method, which is already written and working. Text dumps of single tables are supported by all current SQL dbms, as far as I know. If you move to a different dbms, you'll have to change the name of the dump program and the arguments to it. I can't imagine why you'd need to change the reference file, but I suppose that *could* happen.

The "database way" is really just to select the data you *expect* to be in the database, and see if it's really there. That's pretty much what you're doing now, and what pgTap does with perhaps greater flexibility.

To increase maintainability (to reduce duplication), you *could* generate the INSERT statements from the reference data, or you *could* generate the reference data from the INSERT statements. I can imagine development environments where that would be a wise thing to do, but I don't know whether yours is one of them.